# Deserialize a list of objects with partial data?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to update just one column of the Picture objects

```
class PictureListViewer(APIView):
    def patch(self, request, album_pk, format=None):
        serializer = PictureSerializer(Picture.objects.all(), data = request.data, many = True, partial = True)
        if serializer.is_valid():  #throws exception here
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I keep getting error at the validation part, it seems like the serializer does not like QuerySet

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'album'

In the PictureSerializer I have defined ListSerializer as well as custom update() method

Comment: Does your model have an `album` attribute?

Comment: absolutely, album is a ForeignKey that points to Album object

Comment: Can you post serializer and model code, looks like some misconfiguration.

Comment: The issue had been "fixed":  In my Picture model I had set `unique_together`. While DRF's `UniqueTogetherValidator`  was having trouble identifying a list of objects even though `many=true` was in the serializer. This is either a DRF bug or my incompetent programming knowledge